# iOS : How to autostop the sound file on the PickerViewController when user select a new picker?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, uipickerview

I have one music player with multiple sounds. My question is when i pick one of the object in the picker view, it will play automatically, but when i select a new one, the old sound won't stop. The sound will overlap with the new one. How do I autostop it? Here is my code for troubleshoot :

H File :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface musixGreetingViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{

    UIPickerView       *picker;
    UILabel            *musicTitle;
    NSMutableArray     *musicList;
    AVAudioPlayer      *audioPlayer;


}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *musicTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *musicList;

-(IBAction)playSelectedMusic:(id)sender;


@end
```

M File :

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         musicList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"m1",@"m2",@"m3",@"m6",@"m4", @"m5",nil];
    }

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component


{

    //[self playSelectedMusic:self];

    if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m1"])
    {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"m1" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

        pickerView.delegate = self;
        [theAudio play];

        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                  @"m1",
                                  [musicList objectAtIndex:row]];
        musicTitle.text = resultString;


    }


    if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"m2"])
    {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"m2" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

        pickerView.delegate = self;
        [theAudio play];



        NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                  @"m2",
                                  [musicList objectAtIndex:row]];
        musicTitle.text = resultString;


    }

-(IBAction)playSelectedMusic:(id)sender{

I want the music play here, how to do so without autoplay the music in the picker view?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will reset the player to the beginning:

```
[theAudio setCurrentTime:0.0];
```

Comment: [theAudio setCurrentTime:0.0];[theAudio play]; I put it this way but doesn't work.

Comment: where do i put that [theAudio setCurrentTime:0.0];

Comment: You have to add this line for every option...so that you can start another music...i couldn't understand what you r trying to do...

Comment: I have added  [theAudio setCurrentTime:0.0];
        [theAudio play] in all the if statement. Is that what you mean ? But still doesn't work. I am still beginner so my level until this far.

Comment: I would prefer when user select the picker, it doesn't play the song first until the user press play button. I'm still figure out this, but my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: try to create new project and include my code with that...your above format is correct...you just do and try once again..

Comment: hi, i have tried to create new project but same problem occur. the sound overlapping when i click the new music

Comment: Sorry i said what i have known...you can check out AVAudioPlayer documentation and get clear about whay they mean for stop,play,currenttime and all those...all the best..